# disable (authorization) header logging for cy.request

Tags: cypress

I use Cypress for testing an Angular application. When setting up the environment I need some backend stuff so I use `cy.request()` with an authorization header.

The problem is, when this request fails the complete request including the authorization header will be logged. As long as I am in a local env this is no problem, but I also run those tests in a CI pipeline (Teamcity).

Is there a way, one can remove / redact the authorization header in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the `cy.request()` command will only fail when the `response.status` is a failure code.

If so, you could add the `failOnStatusCode:false` option and handle the error in the following `.then()` callback.

This is an example to experiment with

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/invalid',              // going to fail
  body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1 }),
  headers: { 
    "Authorization": "Bearer xyz", 
  },
  log: false, 
  failOnStatusCode: false                      
}).then(response => {
  expect(response.status).to.be.lt(400)  // just logs "expected 404 to be below 400"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it took me a while to find a solution. It doesn't help to pass the `{ log: false }` option to `cy.request`, because that doesn't apply to the output message of a test failure. Instead, you can add something like this to your support file:

```
Cypress.on('fail', e => {
    const authRegex = /("Authorization": "Bearer )([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)"/;
    const authHeaderMatch = e.message.match(authRegex);

    if (authHeaderMatch !== null) {
        const headerFix = authHeaderMatch[1] + authHeaderMatch[2].slice(0, 10) + '[...FILTERED]"';
        e.message = e.message.replace(authRegex, headerFix);
    }

    // Rethrow the error in order to retain the test's failed status
    throw e;
});
```